# How to correctly compare scala.xml Nodes?

Tags: xml, scala, compare

I am trying to compare two XMLs in scala, but the comparison made by scala does not make sense.
How to do it correctly?

Suppose we have two xmls:

```
import scala.xml.Elem

val xml1: Elem = <A><B>   SomeText   </B></A>

val xml2: Elem = <A>
  <B>   SomeText   </B>
</A>
```

And then i compare it and i get strange results:

```
xml1.diff(xml2)
// res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<A><B>   SomeText   </B></A>)

xml1.mkString eq xml2.mkString
// res1: Boolean = false

xml1.descendant == xml2.descendant
// res2: Boolean = false

xml1 == xml2
// res5: Boolean = false

xml1.equals(xml2)
// res6: Boolean = false
```

Calling `trim` on the xmls would not work, as this will break XMLs itself:

```
scala.xml.Utility.trim(xml1)
// res3: scala.xml.Node = <A><B>SomeText</B></A>

scala.xml.Utility.trimProper(xml1)
// res4: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = <A><B>SomeText</B></A>
```

What is the correct way to compare XMLs in scala (without any additional libraries)? Is there any?
Why scala does that strange comparison?

Scala version `2.11.11`.

**UPDATE**

What puzzles me here - it is that from my point of view these are exactly the same XMLs - both have root node `<A>`, node `<A>` contains node `<B>` and node `<B>` contains `SomeText`.

Same if it would be JSON, for example.

`{ "A" : { "B" : "   SomeText   " } }`

```
{ 
   "A" : {
       "B" : "   SomeText   " 
   } 
}
```

From my perspective it does not matter how XML is written - on multiple lines or on single line. It is still the same XML - same structure and same contents.
Am I wrong about this point?

Comment: Why do you think that `scala.xml.Utility.trim` breaks XMLs?

Comment: Because it removes spaces inside my `<B>` node. It changes contents.

Comment: `trim` removes all the whitespaces in the node. It works correctly. You need to determine in what cases you need to trim the node and in what cases you don't.

Comment: I don't need to trim. I need to compare. `trim` is here to show that it does not help me.

Comment: So you want specific comparison where whitespaces are ignored if current `Node` has other `Node`s and if `Node` has only `Text` then whitespaces matter?

Comment: @Duelist he wants to compare the data represented in XML format, not the strings happening to be XML data. It means ignoring how XML is formatted: as a single line, multiline.

It's like in Zoran's answer below, but not manually navigating the tree. There may be Scala XML's way for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think comparison of these two xml as strings will work because the second xml has line breaks and as string it will resolve to \n       **SomeText**   \n  , so that is the reason why you always get false when you compare it as strings.

When you use trim, those line breaks and whitespaces are removed, so if you don't want that to be ignored you might rather compare each individual sub-element, e.g.

```
(xml1 \ "B").text == (xml2 \ "B").text
```

And define your own criterias for equality.

On the other side, direct comparison of nodes A from both xml also doesn't work, as line breaks and whitspaces in front of node B are treated as children elements of node A in xml2. For that reason, node A from xml2 will have 3 children (text node "\n", node B and text node "\n"), while node A from xml1 will only have 1 child (node B). Comparison of those nodes A will always be false.

You can check this article [oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/wang-whitespace.html](http://oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/wang-whitespace.html) to find more information about whitespaces before and after elements. It's java example, but pretty much the same idea. Also this one might be useful to understand the problem: [xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/#s3](http://xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/#s3). You will understand from it that whitespaces and line breaks are treated as child elements of the parent node and that's the reason why direct comparison of these two elements will not work.

Comment: yeah. i understand that i can write my own function to compare XMLs, but i don't understand why the standard once works the way they works. I've updated my answer. Also +1 for you for the answer.

Comment: Regarding your question if two xml nodes are the same. They are not the same. xml1 has element A, which has 1 child element B, while xml2 has element A which has 3 child elements: text "\n", element B and text "\n"

Comment: For that reason, direct comparison of nodes A from xml1 and A from xml2 will never give true. It will always fail on the number of children these nodes have.

Comment: Is it somwhere defined in specification of XML? I always thought that in XML structure matters, not the formatting. I mean in both my examples I only wanted to have <B> inside <A> without any text. And, basically, what you say means that one liner XML will never be equal to same XML pretty printed. Which is stupid from my point of view.

Comment: Check this article https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/wang-whitespace.html. It's java example and discuss about whitespaces before elements, but pretty much the same idea. Also this one might be useful to understand the problem: http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/#s3.

Comment: Thank you. I accept your answer. Could you, please, edit your answer to add the links there, so other could see that without need to go through comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Vladislav, are your nodes sorted so you can easily compare them as Strings ?
If so, you just need a few normalization :

```
Seq(xml1, xml2).map{_.mkString.replace("\n","").replaceAll("> +<","><")}
    .foreach{println}

<A><B>   SomeText   </B></A>
<A><B>   SomeText   </B></A>
```

If not, just apply the above transformation, map the sequence to `XML.loadString` and finally use this compare method : https://violoncello2011.wordpress.com/2014/09/02/compare-two-unordered-xmls-using-scala/

```
val xml1: Elem = <A><C>Added C</C><B>   SomeText   </B></A>

val xml2: Elem = <A>
  <B>   SomeText   </B>
  <C>Added C</C>
</A>

val Seq(x1,x2) = Seq(xml1, xml2).map{_.mkString.replace("\n","").replaceAll("> +<","><")}
  .map{XML.loadString}

//Here we define the (missing) ADT used in the link above
trait Difference
case object NoDifference extends Difference
case class ActualDifference(str: String) extends Difference
```

[... you can copy the code from the blog here ...]

```
println(compare(x1, x2))
```

output :

```
NoDifference
```

Comment: yeah. i understand that i can write my own function to compare XMLs, but i don't understand why the standard once works the way they works. Besides, if one wants to compare something as strings than it would be logically to call `toString` and then compare. I've updated my answer. Also +1 for you for the answer.